# Edit Form option is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I am trying to hide few of my columns in SharePoint online using Edit Form option, however I cant see this option.

[image]

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you trying to hide columns from list forms or list view? I think list forms, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to hide certain columns in the Edit Form?

**Please following steps:**

1.Go to the SharePoint list as site admin

2.Click " **+ New** " button to open the Edit Form

[image]

3.Click the **Edit form icon** in the upper right corner and select "**Edit columns**"

[image]

4.On the Edit columns in the form panel, uncheck the columns that you want to hide. For example, I want to hide [Due Date] and [System] column

5.Click **Save** button

[image]

6.Refresh page and you will find that these columns have disappeared from the Edit Form

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing ,it was useful

Comment: Thanks for your information. I was more looking at hiding the column in the new form.

Comment: Hi Harris. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved.  Looking forward to our next cooperation.